# In perl, How can I refer to a hash element in a parent hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I've written a function to print hashes in a prescribed order by including an ordered key array as an element of the hash.

Since there may be many subhashes with the same order, I want to be able to put the order string in the parent hash, and refer to it in each subhash.
I can't get it to work, as shown in the code fragment below.

Is there a way to do this?

```
$hr={
    Order => [qw(Sp Ls)],
    OrderSP => [qw(a b)],
    Sp => {
        a =>-1, 
        b => -1,
        Order => @{$hr->{OrderSP}}
        },
    Ls => { 
        c => -1,
        d => -1,
        Order => [qw(c d)]
        }
    }; 
print "\n\@{\$hr->{OrderSP}} = ",@{$hr->{OrderSP}}; # ab
print "\n\@{\$hr->{Ls}->{Order}} = ",@{$hr->{Ls}->{Order}}; # cd 
print "\n\@{\$hr->{Sp}->{Order}} = ",@{$hr->{Sp}->{Order}}; # blank

Result:
@{$hr->{OrderSP}} = ab
@{$hr->{Ls}->{Order}} = cd
@{$hr->{Sp}->{Order}} =
```

Comment: Try put brackets around `@{$hr->{OrderSP}}` : `Order => [ @{$hr->{OrderSP}} ]`

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you've parsed something - maybe some XML with XML::Simple? If so, there's probably a better way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this.

Your code has two issues:

1. You're dereferencing the arrayref stored in the parent: `@{$hr->{OrderSP}}`. This makes no sense because a value in a hash must be a single scalar, not a list. Removing `@{` `}` would fix this.
2. The big one: You're trying to use a data structure that doesn't exist yet. While the right-hand side of the assignment is being evaluated (and the hashes, subhashes, etc. are constructed), `$hr` hasn't been touched yet. The actual assignment only happens after the data structure has been built.

Here's a working example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hr = {
    Order   => [qw(Sp Ls)],
    OrderSP => [qw(a b)],
    Sp => {
        a => -1, 
        b => -1,
    },
    Ls => { 
        c => -1,
        d => -1,
        Order => [qw(c d)],
    },
};

$hr->{Sp}{Order} = $hr->{OrderSP};

print "\@{\$hr->{OrderSP}} = @{$hr->{OrderSP}}\n";
print "\@{\$hr->{Ls}->{Order}} = @{$hr->{Ls}->{Order}}\n";
print "\@{\$hr->{Sp}->{Order}} = @{$hr->{Sp}->{Order}}\n";
```

Output:

```
@{$hr->{OrderSP}} = a b
@{$hr->{Ls}->{Order}} = c d
@{$hr->{Sp}->{Order}} = a b
```

The crucial bit is that setting `$hr->{Sp}{Order}` has been split off into a separate step, so it only happens after `$hr->{OrderSP}` has been created (by the assignment to `my $hr`).

Alternatively you could also do this:

```
my $OrderSP = [qw(a b)];
my $hr = {
    Order   => [qw(Sp Ls)],
    OrderSP => $OrderSP,
    Sp => {
        a => -1, 
        b => -1,
        Order => $OrderSP,
    },
    Ls => { 
        c => -1,
        d => -1,
        Order => [qw(c d)],
    },
};
```

This time we don't modify `$hr` after the initial assignment. Instead we store `OrderSP` in a separate variable beforehand, which we can then reference from anywhere.

(By the way, I've also fixed the newlines in your output. `"\n"` is a line *terminator*; i.e. it goes at the end of each line, not the beginning.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your first example is what I did originally. But those Order arrays are big and repetitious, which is why I was trying to get them all to point to one place. Your second example certainly solves the problem, but I was hoping to make the hash self-contained, so I could simply call it with a printOrderedHash function. So, it's a matter of aesthetics, I suppose.